# List of lists - only the first must be numbers, ts(2345) for null assignment where explicitly permitted

Tags: typescript

I am using a library (uPlot) that has a list typing where only the first list in a list must be numbers. `AlignedData` is defined by the library. It looks perfectly OK to me as the `xValues` must be a number (time) and the `yValues` are definitely allowed (and need) to have nulls as not every value is available for every time.

With typescript 4.4.2 and `strict: true` in `tsconfig.json` I get the following result from typescript. Ideally I would like to be able to let typescript know that the part of the list I am assigning a null to is the part where `yValues` applies. It looks like it cannot tell from the guarding loop I have added.

```
type AlignedData = [
    xValues: number[],
    ...yValues: (number | null | undefined)[][],
]

let data: AlignedData = [
    [],            // Times
    [], [], []     // Values, may contain nulls
]

data[0].push(123)
for (let index = 1; index < data.length; index++) {
    data[index].push(null)      // should be OK because yValues may be null but ...
                                // Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to 
                                // parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)
}
```

The following hack makes it run, is there a 'proper' way?

```
    let hackynull: any = null
    data[index].push(hackynull)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it without a type cast. Except don't do `any`, use something more type safe, like `const yValues = data[index] as (number | null | undefined)[]; yValues.push(null);`. Maybe move this `number | null | undefined` array to its own type to make it shorter. If you could create a type like `Exclude<number, 0>`, then you could type it better, but for now it's not possible 
Also you probably meant `index < data.length` and not `index <= data.length` in the loop

Comment: @Alex, thanks. Correct on the <=, the production code differs slightly. I tried the ```yValues ... as``` construct without success, good to know this is possible. I found the intial issue in the process of trying to remove ```any``` use, a very narrow use of any may just remain for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alex for the pointer, coercing typescript to treat the target object as having the correct typing.

```
for (let index = 1; index < data.length; index++) {
    let yValues = data[index] as (number | null)[];
    yValues.push(null)
}
```